# innerHTML não funciona completamente

Tags: javascript

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda para executar um código. O desafio era imprimir números da posição 0 até 15 do array e dizer quais são pares e quais são ímpares. Funciona perfeitamente no console.log, mas não tá funcionando document. Vou colocar a parte em JS e em HTML para melhor compreensão.

```js
var nums = [1, 6, 3, 5, 8, 3, 245, 63, 87, 342, 68, 348, 1002, 14, 7, 12];
function remainder(x){
  for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(x[i]%2==1){
      document.getElementById("msg"+1).innerHTML = x[i]+" is ODD.";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("msg"+1).innerHTML = x[i]+" is EVEN.";
    }
  }
}
remainder(nums);
```

```html
<p id="msg1"></p>
<p id="msg2"></p>
<p id="msg3"></p>
<p id="msg4"></p>
<p id="msg5"></p>
<p id="msg6"></p>
<p id="msg7"></p>
<p id="msg8"></p>
<p id="msg9"></p>
<p id="msg10"></p>
<p id="msg11"></p>
<p id="msg12"></p>
<p id="msg13"></p>
<p id="msg14"></p>
<p id="msg15"></p>
<p id="msg16"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás a usar `.getElementById("msg" + 1)`... ou seja estás sempre a re-escrever o mesmo elemento. Devias usar o `i` para ir acrescentando esse numero. Mas tendo em conta que o `i` começa em `0` tens de acrescentar `+1`. Ou seja:

```
document.getElementById("msg" + (i + 1))
```

Exemplo:

```js
var nums = [1, 6, 3, 5, 8, 3, 245, 63, 87, 342, 68, 348, 1002, 14, 7, 12];

function remainder(x) {
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] % 2 == 1) {
      document.getElementById("msg" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = x[i] + " is ODD.";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("msg" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = x[i] + " is EVEN.";
    }
  }
}
remainder(nums);
```

```html
<p id="msg1"></p>
<p id="msg2"></p>
<p id="msg3"></p>
<p id="msg4"></p>
<p id="msg5"></p>
<p id="msg6"></p>
<p id="msg7"></p>
<p id="msg8"></p>
<p id="msg9"></p>
<p id="msg10"></p>
<p id="msg11"></p>
<p id="msg12"></p>
<p id="msg13"></p>
<p id="msg14"></p>
<p id="msg15"></p>
<p id="msg16"></p>
```